# How to make clone of DSR protocol in ns 2.35?

Tags: adhoc, ns2

i can able to achieve cloning of aodv protocol but for DSR it's very challenging task for me. 
Any help will be appreciated
Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Not quite clear what you want. Edit AODV to DSR in an aodv file.tcl . ... Or edit DSR to AODV in a dsr file.tcl ?  Some aodv-examples https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNTGQ1QWtPenN4Mm8/view?usp=sharing ... And some dsr-examples https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNNFJzNGxRd25Zd3c/view?usp=sharing .... All tcl examples (41.8MB) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNUUpUYWJ6TTdseWc/view?usp=sharing  ....

Comment: thanks sir for your feedback .. i want to clone DSR protocol . .in easy word "changing the name of 'DSR' to 'CloneDSR'(OR any Name)". although DSR is a special case , i couldn't able to figure it out  ...    see this link : (http://surajpatilworld.blogspot.in/2015/02/how-to-clone-protocol-in-ns2.html?showComment=1453530821048#c7079549567985091016)